# Many false positives in a custom SSD model with Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: object-detection-api

My model has 2 classes (no background class) and is trained using transfer learning with ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco. It detects and classifies well the objects it was trained on. However, on new images it also detects many false positive bounding box's of the background. 
Sometimes the background objects that are detected are objects that existed in the coco data set (e.g. a cup), but not only - also a black screen is detected as an object.

1. Can it be that my model features are still sensitive to  the Coco data set objects?
2. I think that on the config file, the relevant part for this issue is the hard_example_miner. However I did not understand how is this related and if I should change my current configuration.

This is the configuration I'm using:

```
hard_example_miner {

num_hard_examples: 3000

iou_threshold: 0.99

loss_type: CLASSIFICATION

max_negatives_per_positive: 3

in_negatives_per_image: 3

}
```

Should I make any changes to this? Or any other solutions to improve the model on background images?

Comment: what are the confidence scores of false positives, are they all very high or not?  What is the size of your training data?

Comment: the confidence scores of the false positive are very high (0.99). The size of the training data is 1400 images (about 800 and 600 in each class). the size of the images are 300X300.